# Decrypt/Decrypt Arabic string

Tags: c#

How to encrypt/decrypt arabic text in C#

```
    public static string Encrypt(string pDataToEncrypt)
    {

        ASCIIEncoding textConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();
        RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
        byte[] toEncrypt;

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, IV);

        MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor,            CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        toEncrypt = textConverter.GetBytes(pDataToEncrypt);

        csEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
        csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)msEncrypt.Length);
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string pDataToDecrypt)
    {
        RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
        byte[] fromEncrypt;

        //Encoding asciiEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;

        fromEncrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(pDataToDecrypt);
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = myRijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, IV);

        MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);
        CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csDecrypt);

        return sr.ReadToEnd();

    }
```

when i try to encrypt its return "????" question marks

thanks in advance

Comment: Fix the title. I think it should be `Encrypt/Decrypt`

Comment: Can you provide some Arabic text to test this with?

Comment: كرم الرمحي this example of text

Comment: Mr.Soner, did you solve it ??

Comment: are you using WPF, Windows Form or ASP.NET Web Forms?

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
UnicodeEncoding()
```

instead of

```
ASCIIEncoding()
```

Comment: .. because ASCII contains only Latin letters, not Arabic ones. Unicode contains *all*.

Comment: I cant use UnicodeEncoding() and ASCIIEncoding() in the memory stream and stream reader !